# What happened to constraint layout and its dimension ratio attribute in 2.0.2 version?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an ImageView setup like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/video_file_item_image_height"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
```

it looks like this

[image]

but with

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
```

ImageView is not visible

[image]

**Update**

Version 2.0.3 it's still not fixed, it only works if you don't set dp for height (e.g. you set `wrap_content` instead) and `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=` is also required, but it works then differently, I need to set height in DPI! It worked like this in 2.0.1 and `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf=` wasn't required to be set

Comment: What does Android Studio's Layout Inspector show is the size of the `ImageView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare width 0, height 131

Comment: What happens if you use `"W,16:9"` for the value?

Comment: @BenP. I've tried it already, but nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170313444

The recommended workaround is to add this to your `ConstraintLayout` tag:

```
app:layout_optimizationLevel="cache_measures"
```

Comment: I also have a similar issue with app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,2:3" on Android TV where portrait images are cropped from bottom. The issue is seen after I updated the constraint layout to 2.0.1, it used to work on 1.1.3. Above solution also doesn't help me. Surprisingly same layout works on mobile.